# Assign color to country in Google maps API

Tags: google-maps

I am using Google API maps.
I want to assign different color to different country for example in England I want to draw each city in different color.
How I can do it with JavaScript API V3?
Do I need to use polygons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use either polygons or a KMLLayer. And for that, you need to provide your own source of data. http://naturalearthdata.com is a good source of public domain data. But Google doesn't provide the boundary information.

Comment: is it possible to do it with using a diffrerent google API and still have map like google chart ? does i still get the same result ?

Comment: No Google API has that data down to the city level. Using Google Chart Tools you can get down to State/Province level, or certain US metropolitan areas.
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Comment: i looked on the example in https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart and I saw char accoridng to city ( Rome, Milan ,...) so as far as I understand it is possile to get to city level also ib google chart tools so what is the diffrerent ?

Comment: You can put markers around the cities, yes, but that doesn't give you access to the boundaries of the city. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: What do you mean access to the boundaries ? if I want to assign color for each country or city what the disadvantage of the Google chart ? I didn't undersand the meaning of the access to the boundaries

Comment: I meant the city borders. If you just want dots over cities of different colors, the Geo Chart in Chart Tools is perfect for you

Comment: @Mano Marks: The site http://naturalearthdata.org no longer appears to be online.